# Per-group repetitions of another captured group

Tags: regex, sed

Say I have a large input stream with structure:

```
key1 valA,valB
key2 valC,valD,valE
```

The number of values per-key is unbounded, as is the key/value text, besides predefined delimiters ',' and ' '.

Is there a sed one-liner to "flatten" it by line?

```
key1 valA
key1 valB
key2 valC
key2 valD
key2 valE
```

I realize this is a very simple Awk or Perl script.  Just wondering if it can be done with straight-up regex.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is here buddy:

```
AMD$ awk '{gsub(/,/,"\n"$1" ")}1' File
key1 valA
key1 valB
key2 valC
key2 valD
key2 valE
```

Just substitute all `,`s in the line with (`newline` followed by the `first field` followed by `space`). Then print all the lines (thats what `1` is for). Thats it.

Comment: I realize this is a very simple Awk or Perl script. Just wondering if it can be done with straight-up regex.